# Interface/gererics usage in c#

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have 2 classes that do a pretty similar job but returns different models.

```
public class WorkerCars
{
    public async Task<Cars> FetchCars(SomeDBdataCars dbData){ //Some codehere }
}
public class WorkerShips
{
    public async Task<Ships> FetchShips(SomeDBdataShips dbData){ //Some codehere }
}
```

Database models are pretty the same with some extra fields in SomeDBdataShips.

```
public class SomeDBdataCars 
{
    public string EngineName {get; set;}
    public string MaterialName {get; set;}
    public int MaxSpeed {get; set;}
    public int MinSpeed {get; set;}
}

public class SomeDBdataShips 
{
     public string EngineName {get; set;}
     public int MaxSpeed {get; set;}
     public int MinSpeed {get; set;}
     public long Price {get; set;}
}
```

Output models I use for client side:

```
public class Cars 
{
    public string EngineName {get; set;}
    public string MaterialName {get; set;}
    public int MaxSpeed {get; set;}
    public int MinSpeed {get; set;}
    public int AvgSpeed {get; set;}
}

public class Ships 
{
    public string EngineName {get; set;}
    public int MaxSpeed {get; set;}
    public int MinSpeed {get; set;}
    public long Price {get; set;}
}
```

The solution for optimization I see is to make generic class *Fetcher* of FetchCars and FetchShips that will return some generic model that could be used and parsed in Workers classes.

Comment: So, what exactly is your question?

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to pluralize classes unless it makes sense to do so. For example `Ships` should be `Ship`. When you return `Task<Ships>`, you are actually returning a single `Ship`. It affects code readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see, there is common logic for both of your models. The fact about `WorkerCars` and `WorkerShips` classes is that they can 'fetch' some data from input to output. So that common behavior can be extracted to generic interface. Lets call it `IFetcher` for example:

```
 public interface IFetcher<in TIn, TOut>
 {
     Task<TOut> FetchAsync(TIn data);
 }
```

And both of your worker classes will implement this interface like this:

```
public class WorkerCars: IFetcher<SomeDBdataCars, Cars>
{
    public async Task<Cars> FetchAsync(SomeDBdataCars data)
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class WorkerShips: IFetcher<SomeDBdataShips, Ships>
{
    public async Task<Ships> FetchAsync(SomeDBdataShips data)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```